# Draw a parabola with 3 given points canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to draw a perfect curve / parabola in an html5 canvas. The 3 {x;y} coordinates of the points are given. I tried with a bezierCurveTo or a quadraticCurveTo, but the curve won't go in the middle point.

The result I want ( the blue doted curve, and the blue one ) : [Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAxE5.png)

The result I have : [Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fkY4.png)

Code :

```
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#00478a';
      ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x1AtRatio, 30);
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(criticalSectionAtRatio, 100, x2AtRatio, 30);

      ctx.stroke();
```

Where x1AtRatio - x2AtRatio - criticalSectionAtRatio are the given x by user input and 30 - 100 - 30 are the y

Comment: Please edit the question with a [mcve] of the code being used so far

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

### Control points define slopes

You will need to use two beziers as the curve will not pass through the control point.

The control points set the slopes of the curve out from the last point and in to the next point.

The example (below) draws a parabola using two curves. The function `drawCurve()`

- I draw it twice once scaled and once normal.
- Control points are blue.
- The three points on the curve are red
- The slopes are in green.

For example

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// drawScaled
ctx.setTransform(2,0,0,2,-50, -55);
drawAll();

// without scale
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,-50, 0);
drawAll();

function drawCurve() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.moveTo(100 - 30, 30);  // start left side
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
        100 - 30 / 2, 100,     // controls point sets slope out from start and into center
        100, 100               // center point
    );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
        100 + 30 / 2, 100,     // control point sets slope out from center and into last point
        100 + 30, 30           // last point
    );
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawAll() {
    // points on curve
    drawPoint(100-30, 30);
    drawPoint(100, 100);
    drawPoint(100+30, 30);

    // Control points
    drawPoint(100 - 30 / 2, 100, "#00F");
    drawPoint(100 + 30 / 2, 100, "#00F");

    // Draw line through all points to show slopes
    drawLine(100-30, 30, 100 - 30 / 2, 100);
    drawLine(100 - 30 / 2, 100, 100, 100);
    drawLine(100, 100, 100 + 30 / 2, 100);
    drawLine(100 + 30 / 2, 100, 100 + 30, 30);

    // Draw curve
    drawCurve();
}




function drawPoint(x,y,col = "red") {
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
}
function drawLine(x,y, x1, y1, col = "#0A08") {
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```